Apache: htaccess domain redirects except for Let's Encrypt well-known folder
I am using Apache > 2.4.x and want to set-up htaccess domain/ path based redirects except for the Let's Encrypt "well-known" path.
How do I do that?
www.example.country -> www.example.com/country/
www.example.country/x/y -> www.example.com/country/x/y
etc.
but keeping www.example.country/.well-known/acme-challenge/ path untouched
I am thinking about the below but cannot find the issue
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(?:.well-known|.well-known/acme-challenge)[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/country/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

or..
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/\.well-known/.+ - [END]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/country/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]

what am I doing wrong here?
